How to get Digikam to display all 4 digits of the year in thumbnails and tooltips
Digikam 8.3.0 on Linux Mint 21.3
Dates shown on thumbnails and tooltips only show the last 2 digits of the year.  I've got a bunch of old family photos going back to the 1800's.  The dates are correct I just want to see all 4 digits of the dates.  e.g. "1/1/1901" instead of the ambiguous "1/1/01".
Is there a way to force all 4 digits of the year to be displayed (other than digging down into the metadata).  Thanks.

This question is similar to: How to change date format in digikam (day/month/year instead of month/day/year). If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I've just added dates to my icon views (configure/views/icons), and they're displaying as full dates with four figures for the year. There doesn't seem to be a specific setting, so I would look at the OS configuration (as xenoid suggested). If you open a file manager and look at the date column, how are they displayed there?
